# Using Python with Playwright, how to get the value of an element?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to get an email that is on a website, by copying the style, but I'm not having success with it. The process of navigating through the website and find the email is working perfectly, the only issue is to copy the email address.

I've tried to get the attribute of the field showing the email, but I'm getting the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\RMBORGE\Desktop\PythonLib\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line
> 21, in <module>
>     email = page.locator('xpath= //*[@id="cphMain_hlOrgInboundEmail"]').get_attribute() TypeError:
> get_attribute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Please see my code below:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time

el = "https://www.getmail.com"


p = sync_playwright().start()
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
page = browser.new_page()
page.goto(el)
owner = page.fill('xpath=//*[@id="cphMain_MyBA"]', "30291726")
search = page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="cphMain_btnSearch"]').click()
time.sleep(3)
name = page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="cphGrid_InvoicesGrid_PartnerOrgName_0"]').click()
#trying to get the attribute of the field
email = page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="cphMain_hlOrgInboundEmail"]').get_attribute()
print(email)
```

The code of the website was written like that:

```
"<a id="cphMain_hlOrgInboundEmail" href="mailto:email@gmail.com" style="font-weight:bold;">email@gmail.com</a>"
```

Comment: `get_attribute()` need some name - like `get_attribute("href")` or `get_attribute("style")`

Comment: XPaths are [discouraged](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/other-locators#xpath-locator): "warning We recommend prioritizing [user-visible locators](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators#quick-guide) like text or accessible role instead of using XPath that is tied to the implementation and easily break when the page changes." That said, when you have an id, why not use a CSS selector `"#cphMain_MyBA"`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `inner_text` for this:

```py
email = page.locator.inner_text("#cphMain_hlOrgInboundEmail")
print(email)
```

Comment: the statement was giving me an error, but I changed to email.inner_text
the issue is that the print is not showing the email, it's showing the following: 
<Locator frame=<Frame name= url='https://www.energylink.com/XrefOrg/OrgXrefDetail.aspx?Context=Outbound&OrgXrefOpId=1140865'> selector='xpath=//*[@id="cphMain_hlOrgInboundEmail"]'>

Comment: How about you use a CSS selector instead of an XPath. updated the ans.